# Cannot Create BuildFire Plugin With Angular

Tags: buildfire

Githubs password authentication was removed. See the console below:

```
me@me-MBP BuildFireSDK % buildfire plugin init NixCodeAngular angular
 ______       _ _     _______ _          
 | ___ \     (_) |   | |  ___(_)         
 | |_/ /_   _ _| | __| | |_   _ _ __ ___ 
 | ___ \ | | | | |/ _` |  _| | | '__/ _ \
 | |_/ / |_| | | | (_| | |   | | | |  __/
 \____/ \__,_|_|_|\__,_\_|   |_|_|  \___|

Creating Plugin NixCodeAngular with tempalte angular
Username for 'https://github.com': myemail@gmail.com
Password for 'https://myemail@github.com': 
Cloning into '/Users/me/Development/admins/nixcode-buildfire-2/BuildFireSDK/plugins/NixCodeAngular'...
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BuildFire/angularPluginTemplate.git/'

Error: Cloning into '/Users/me/Development/admins/nixcode-buildfire-2/BuildFireSDK/plugins/NixCodeAngular'...
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BuildFire/angularPluginTemplate.git/'

    at toError (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/promise.js:90:14)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/promise.js:61:36
    at Git.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:214:18)
    at Git.fail (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:1475:18)
    at fail (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:1433:20)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/buildfire-cli/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:1442:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Are you sure BuildFire CLI provides angular template? Please follow this guide [here](https://medium.com/@attilabuturla/creating-plugins-with-the-buildfire-cli-7592522ed277)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a personal token for the password field, check [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls) for more info and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) on how to create it.